# How to read custom User Profile properties with Office Graph

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I've created a few custom user profile properties on O365 Admin Center which can be edited and displayed on Delve profile page.

Followed these steps to do it: 
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/406878

I expected to get those properties on Office Graph API using
graph.microsoft.com/beta/me 
or
graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/(id)

but the custom properties aren't returned.

How can we read custom User Profile properties with Office Graph Rest API?

Answer (score 2):

/me and /users/(id) only return few default properties of user. Please use $select query parameter to specific list of properties that you interested in. For example, to get skills and schools property, issue request like "/me?$select=skills,schools" .

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The output is the same if I use a property name that wasn't there already in the original output.
For instance: 
/me?$select=accountEnabled works, giving the value of that property
/me?$select=myCustomProperty does not work, giving the same output as /me

Comment: Can you share request-id response header and timestamp of such a request?

Comment: Response Headers
{
    "content-type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8",
    "cache-control": "private",
    "client-request-id": "d46a9fee-4f0c-41e0-bdc2-a4082704058c",
    "request-id": "d46a9fee-4f0c-41e0-bdc2-a4082704058c"
}

Comment: The custom properties that you are interested in is not available through the API yet.

Comment: It has been a while, do you have any idea if this has been scheduled, @SriramDhanasekaran-MSFT ?